# CSS Flexbox: How to arrange three Items in a Row, but two of them below each other?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Assumed we have this simple CSS flexbox layout:

```css
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    }

.flex-item:nth-child(1) {
    order: 0;
    }

.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
    order: 1;
    align-self: flex-start;
    }

.flex-item:nth-child(3) {
    order: 1;
    align-self: flex-end;
    }

.flex-item {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
   <div class="flex-item"></div>
   <div class="flex-item"></div>
   <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Description of the issue:**

Unfortunately `flex-item` 2 and 3 are not located at the right edge below each other, although they are both set to `order: 1`.

---

**Question:**

How can I arrange `flex-item 2` to be at the upper right edge, while `flex-item 3` is located at the lower right edge (item 1 should remain vertically centered at left edge)?

I did not yet figure out on how to arrange all three items in a row, but the latter two items below each other within this row.

Comment: like that? - https://i.ibb.co/t8vmVDj/image.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are trying to do that.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
.flex-container-col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(1) {
    order: 0;
    align-self: flex-center;
    }

.box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item box"></div>
  <div class="flex-item flex-container-col">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to both item 2 and 3 top of the right edge together, you can delete justify-content in flex-container-col so they will unite at the top. Hope works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a block to be at up right, one at the center and other at the bottom right, then you can use this snippet. The `flex item 1` should be at `flex-start`, the `flex item 3` should be at the `flex end` and the `flex item 2` should be where it is.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    }

.flex-item:nth-child(1) {
    order: 0;
    align-self: flex-start;
    }

.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
    order: 1;
    }

.flex-item:nth-child(3) {
    order: 1;
    align-self: flex-end;
    }

.flex-item {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
   <div class="flex-item"></div>
   <div class="flex-item"></div>
   <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```